# 'function' object has no attribute 'get' error in django

Tags: python, django

greetings dear django experts,
i am having an issue with my website i am using the defualt login view in django from

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
```

the code is working
like this inside the urls.py file :

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='website/login.html'), name='login-page'),
```

but using this methode i don't have a view inside my views.py file. the problem is i need to define a view inside my viwes.py to record logs for any one accessing this page the problem is when i tried the following code i get the error "'function' object has no attribute 'get'"
[image: error snapshot]

the code that gives me the error is as the following:
views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views  

def login(request):
    ip = get_client_ip(request)
    logger.info(f'user access: {request.user} via ip:{ip}')
    return auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='website/login.html')
```

urls.py

```
 path('login/',views.login, name='login-page'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.LoginView.as_view()` does *not* process the request, it simply returns a function that will *dispatch* the request, you thus need to call the function that is the result of `.as_view(…)` with the `request` as parameter:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views  

def login(request):
    ip = get_client_ip(request)
    logger.info(f'user access: {request.user} via ip:{ip}')
    return auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='website/login.html')(request)
```

That being said, it looks a bit odd to do this. Why not just subclass the `LoginView` and register that view?

You thus can do this with:

```
# appname/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name='website/login.html'

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
        ip = get_client_ip(request)
        logger.info(f'user access: {request.user} via ip:{ip}')
```

and then register your `MyLoginView` instead:

```
from appname.views import MyLoginView

path('login/', MyLoginView.as_view(), name='login-page'),
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i know it seems odd but i am building this as website for security testing purposes. thank you for the suggestion